# Angular with several lists into one controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean

Ok, I have just edited this question a bit, because I figured some of it out by myself.
I wanted to get a list from another controller into the controller that i'm working on.

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
Annonce.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, annoncer) {
    Land.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, lande){
    Aktivitet.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, aktiviteter){
    var all = lande.concat(annoncer,aktiviteter);
    res.jsonp(all);
    });
  });
 });
};
```

My view for that:
In top i define my controller:

```
    <section data-ng-controller="AnnonceController" data-ng-init="findOne()">
```

And Im making a select list, from where i want to access one of the three lists.

```
<select class="selectpicker">
                <option ng-repeat="annonce in annoncer">{{annonce.landeNavn}}</option>
                </select>
```

It works, but now it is takes all of the lists and outputs it with a lot of empty ones, I guess its because i'm am using concat.
Is there any better methods? 
Because I only want to get the Land list from the other controller outputtet.

Comment: Need to be a lot more specific about where your problem is. See [ask]

Comment: Just took my factories from the others into my controller and did a query for all of them in my $scope.find:  $scope.aktiviteter = Aktiviteter.query(); Thanks for your help... ;-)